# How can I replace an image being shown via JS?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I want to embed Wanelo's share button.

This is the embed code:

```
<a class="wanelo-save-button"
  href="//wanelo.com/"
  data-url=""
  data-title=""
  data-image=""
  data-price=""></a><script async="true" type="text/javascript" src="//cdn-saveit.wanelo.com/bookmarklet/3/save.js"></script>
```

When I embed it, I get this button:

[image: button]

I want to replace that button with their icon, which looks like this:

[image]

Being new to JS, I am unable to understand how I can swap that button from being generated and have this icon be in it's place while still making the share feature work.

Here's their link: http://wanelo.com/about/buttons#save-button
My JSFIDDLE:

http://jsfiddle.net/VCG8c/

Please point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The button is being loaded dynamically via JS with inline CSS.  So in the anchor tag, do this:

```
style="background:none !important;"
```

Comment: Overriding 3rd party crap like this is a perfect example of the 1 or 2 times where `!important;` is kinda acceptable.

Comment: @sheriffderek on firefox it doesn't seem to work.  any ideas on how to hide it there?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, here is a the [updated version of your fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/VCG8c/2/), all nice and working.  Basically, the little JS snippet at "save.js" changes your anchor by adding an appropriate background image (in this case, the rectangular button that says "Wanelo").  So, that will need to be replaced inline - this will change the background image to the one you want.  Of course, the default CSS style associated with "wanelo-save-button" looks like crap, so you'll need to make some stylistic changes in a custom class.

The JS:

```
setTimeout(function(){
    //Get the anchor element
    var anchor = document.querySelectorAll('a.wanelo-save-button')[0];

    //Change the backgroundImage property
    anchor.style.backgroundImage = 'url("https://i.stack.imgur.com/X0r5e.png")';

    //Add an appropriate CSS class for styling
    anchor.className += ' myCheckerBackground'
}, 3000);
```

And the CSS:

```
a.wanelo-save-button.myCheckerBackground{
    height: 88px;
    width: 101px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;    
}
```

You'll notice that I used "setTimeout."  This is due to a limitation on jsFiddle.  In the production environment, you'll want to place your custom js file AFTER save.js loads, then in THAT file create a [DOMContentLoaded listener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Reference/Events/DOMContentLoaded) to make sure the first Wanelo image has loaded before you modify it.

Answer (score 0):

```
<a class="wanelo-save-button" href="//wanelo.com/">
    <img src="whatever image you want here" alt="">
</a>
<script async="true" type="text/javascript" src="//cdn-saveit.wanelo.com/bookmarklet/3/save.js</script>
```

Works.

Comment: THanks.  I tried that but while it shows the icon, it still shows the button, which i don't want.

Comment: can you please help me here? I used Captain Kirk's method since yours didn't work the way I wanted and the one captain Kirk gave works on chrome but not on firefox.  Please help!