# How can I remove an image being shown by JS?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I've asked this question before:

[How can I replace an image being shown via JS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23438332/how-can-i-replace-an-image-being-shown-via-js/23438492?noredirect=1#23438492)

While I received an answer, it partially helped me.  I was able to override the image being shown from the JS in chrome and safari but in firefox I am still getting the image being shown by JS and my own image that I want to override.

Based on the answer I got in that other question, here's the updated code:

```
<a class="wanelo-save-button" href="//wanelo.com/" data-url="" data-title="" data-image=""
   data-price="">
<img src="http://i.imgur.com/CKibmqj.png" />
</a>
<script async="true" type="text/javascript" src="//cdn-saveit.wanelo.com/bookmarklet/3/save.js"></script>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/VCG8c/3/

Example: http://www.abercrombie.com/shop/us/womens-new-arrivals/jorie-shirt-2255074_03

On this page in the bottom right you'll see the icon i have.  I want to do it like that but can't seem to figure out how to do it right.

I want the square icon to show and not the button behind it.  The link should still work.  I am new to all of this and I am puzzled.  Can any of you just point me in the right direction.   What should I do to hide that button?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this to your CSS stylesheet:

```
.wanelo-save-button{
    background:none !important
}
```

This will prevent the background change from their script.

I tried this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/VCG8c/4/) in Firefox and it works fine.

Comment: i can't believe i didn't try that!